# how to execute the Non - Static class in salesforce

Tags: apex

How to execute the Non - Static class in salesforce and also no need to create a Instance of the class. give below i post the class

```
public class RetrieveRe{
   public List<contact> DisRecord()
   {
       List<contact> C = [select id,name from contact limit 10];
       system.debug('##'+C);
       return C;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is really basic stuff. You should start by reading this [Trailhead tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/force_com_dev_beginner/modules/apex_database).

Comment: @Martin Lezer, i know about this execution flow - If static methods call the classname.methodname();
Non - static methods call the Classname createnew Instance and assign to method name();
But i, m not use static , any other alternate way is there .. please tell me..

Comment: @ali Your description of how non-static classes work is incorrect, and may be the source of at least some of your confusion here. I don't have any resources bookmarked that cover the basics of object-oriented programming (OOP for short, and Apex is an OOP language), but that's what I would encourage you to look for. In terms of programming languages, Java is quite closely related to Apex. Finding, and working through, some basic Java tutorials to gain some understanding of basic OOP concepts would probably be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

In Apex, each defined class contains a default constructor with no parameter.

Basically, you could instantiate your class using: `RetrieveRe myClass = new RetrieveRe();`

If you needed to define your own constructor, for example:

```
public class RetrieveRe{
    public RetrieveRe(String myParameter){
        ...
    }
}
```

You could instantiate your class using: `RetrieveRe myClass = new RetrieveRe('Test');`

Then, thanks to previous instantiation, your class instance is stored in your `myClass` variable.

So you can call your method using: `List<Contact> myContacts = myClass.DisRecord();`

Comment: can you please elaborate me..
and why we to use constructor and how to define constructor.

Comment: Static methods are not aware of the context of the class. Typically, if you have to store variables states in a class, you can't use static methods. You use a class with a constructor, then call the methods of this class which are all aware of the current state of the variables inside the class.